# Qt - How to syncronously request data from QObject

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Part of my code are two C++ classes 'ClassA' and 'ClassB' which are both inherited from QObject.

And in some of its methods ClassB needs to syncronously request data stored in ClassA.

ClassA   <----- request data -----   ClassB

Is there Qt API similar to signals/slots which can be used for it?

There are two possible options which I can think of but I am not sure 
if they are architecturally correct:

1) To define Q_INVOKABLE function in ClassA which would return the needed data as its return value and to call it in ClassB.

But I am not sure if Q_INVOKABLE can be used for purposes other than C++/QML bonding and how to register it properly in other cases.

2) To create regular signal/slot pair in ClassB/ClassA respectively.

signal emitted in ClassB would be used to request the data from ClassA and would have a pointer as its input arg which would point to where store the data.
And slot in ClassA would write the data to this pointer.

```
void ClassA::slot(type *ptr)
{
// write data to ptr
}

void ClassB::signal(type *ptr)
```

Comment: why not just adding a method to class A and call it directly?

Comment: The current communication between these two objects is through signals/slots. So I thought there may be smth similar for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want dependency injection. That's a fancy word for simply giving reference of class A to class B, probably as a constructor parameter.

Use `QPointer<ClassA>` if you can decide it's *ClassA* when writing the source code. Then just call any methods of *ClassA* as needed.

If you can't lock the exact class, just know it will be `QObject`, then use `QPointer<QObject>` and use Qt properties or invokable methods (`Q_INVOKABLE` or just a slot with a return value) to request what you want.

As an alternative, if *ClassB* instance can own an instance of *ClassA*, just give a pointer to *ClassA* instance to B, and then make B set itself as parent of A. Then it'll be automatically deleted by the destructor (the usual Qt way of QObject ownership).